# nagios notification problems

Tags: linux, nagios

I use nagios to monitor servers,if the server is down，nagios will send a notification to me that the host is down，but it will also send me many service alert for the down host which said connection refused,How could change configuration to stop nagios to send notification about the service alert when the host is down?

thanks

Comment: You should ask that kind of questions at: http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1):

I use Nagios to monitor many servers/services.

You could, under the web GUI of Nagios, go into the Host or Service Problems (left side menu), click on the Service or Host that you want to disable notifications for. 
On the right hand side "Host Commands" or "Service Commands" > click on "Disable notifications for this host" or "Disable notifications for this service".

-Charlie

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I know this, but I don't want to do it manually, I mean when the host is down,just send the notification for the host. Don't send the service alert even I haven't disable the notification for service. thanks!

Comment: In that case, in the left side menu, go to Process Info, on the right side go to Process Commands > 'Stop executing service checks' to disable service notifications. Leave "Stop executing host checks" enabled.